# Elastisearch queries that are used for APM UI are slow

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm

I have noticed problems with queries returning 500 response when clicking on APM UI on our Kibana GUI. The server makes a request

```
GET /api/apm/ui_filters/local_filters/services?uiFilters=%7B%7D&start=2020-07-07T07%3A08%3A42.818Z&end=2020-07-08T07%3A08%3A42.818Z&filterNames=%5B%22host%22%2C%22agentName%22%5D
```

I have run the request in debug mode, so that I could obtain the query and run it in the Search Profiler  in Kibana. I have run this >

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "processor.event": [
                        "transaction",
                        "error",
                        "metric"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": 1594105722818,
                        "lte": 1594192122818,
                        "format": "epoch_millis"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "observer.version_major": {
                        "gte": 7
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "host": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": []
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "by_terms": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "host.hostname",
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "bucket_count": {
                        "cardinality": {
                            "field": "service.name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "agentName": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": []
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "by_terms": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "agent.name",
                    "order": {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "bucket_count": {
                        "cardinality": {
                            "field": "service.name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I have run it I have recieved the timeout again and I needed to shorten the time interval of the query but when "aggs" are removed I see that the query is really fast. The main problem is on the trasaction index for APM and for 4h I get a 3 second response time while without the "aggs" I have 50ms repsonse time for that index. The main delay is "next_doc" and  "build_scorer".

Could perhaps somebody let me know how I can go on and troubleshoot this as the query can't be changed there is probably something on the APM index or on the ES nodes itself.

The ELK cluster is running in docker and we have 5 nodes (6 CPU 30GB RAM - 10GB JVM, 1TB SSD) with a coordinator node where we run as well Kibana and an APM server. All of this is deployed in GCP in the same zone. I have measured network delay, resource usage and I/O speed and couldn't find anything that would block the speed of the cluster.

The APM loads data for 24h if I change the timerange on the first page to 1h and then select a service and move in there.